# jQuery fade out HTML text when replacing it with new text instead of just appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following little script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').bind('keyup', function(event) {

        if($('#search').val().length == '0') {
            $("#products").html("All Products");
        } else {
            $("#products").html("Searching Products");
        }
    });
});
```

When `#search` has something in it, it shows 'Searching Products', and when empty, it shows 'All Products'. My problem is that it quickly changes with no fade effect, so it looks a bit choppy. How could I have it fade from one to the other, no matter which direction (from empty to typed or from typed to empty) it's going?

Comment: Is `#products` hidden by default ?

Comment: No, it's `All Products` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var search = $("#search")
  , products = $("#products");
  search.bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if (search.val().length === 0 
       || search.val().split(/\s/).every(function(val) {
            return val === ""
          })) 
    {
        if (products.html() === "All Products") {
          return
        };
        products
        .stop(true, false)
        .html("All Products")
        .fadeOut(-1000)
        .fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        if (search.val().length > 0 && products.html() === "Searching Products") {
          return
        };
        products
        .stop(true, false)
        .html("Searching Products")
        .fadeOut(-1000)
        .fadeIn(1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<br />
<div id="products"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want it to keep changing for every character I type, only if it goes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. But from 1 to 2, it should stay on "Searching Product". Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Created a JsBin for your issue [here](http://jsbin.com/wovenajifa/1/edit)

Have basically changed the HTML structure to hold two `<h1>` tags which are hidden and shown up as per requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').bind('keyup', function(event) {
        if($('#search').val().length == '0') {
            $("#productsSearch").hide();
            $("#products").fadeIn(400);
        } else if($('#productsSearch').css('display') == 'none') {
            $("#products").hide();
          $("#productsSearch").fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text">
    <h1 id="products">All Products</h1>
    <h1 id="productsSearch" style="display:none;">Searching Products</h1>
```

Comment: It is best if you describe what your code does, and then *include* it in your post. Can you please edit the code from your JsBin into your answer? If not, this answer may receive downvotes and deletion even though from looking at your link it is an answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for making an edit to the page. However, I think I need to be a little more clear. You need to actually include all of the html code, the css code, and the javascript in your answer. If you do that, it will be in good shape :)

Comment: I did it this one time so you can see what I meant. In the future, it will be up to you :P

Answer (score 1):

Hide then use jQuery fade in 
http://jsfiddle.net/kzs3trfr/36/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').on('keyup', function(event) {
        var length = $(this).val().length;
        console.log(length);
        if(length <= '0') {
            $("#products").hide().html("All Products").stop().fadeIn(400);
        } else if(length == '1' && $('#products').html() != 'Searching Products') {
            $("#products").hide().html("Searching Products").stop().fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
});
```

Kinda messy code but works.

Comment: This works great! Only problem is every character you type, it does the fade in again. Is there a way to only do it on the first change? So only in length goes greater than 0 or less than 1, but not if it goes from 1 to 2, for example.

Comment: I think `fadeOut` instead of `hide` will generate a better effect .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with exact effect and ignoring any type of white space :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search').bind('keyup', function(event) {
            var search_val = $.trim( $('#search').val() ); //lets trim it as well
            if( search_val.length == '0' ) { 
                if( $("#products").html() == "All Products" ) return;
                $("#products").hide().html("All Products").fadeIn(400);
            } else {
                if( $("#products").html() == "Searching Products" ) return;
                $("#products").hide().html("Searching Products").fadeIn(400);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e6er298/1/)

Comment: Only problem is every character you type, it does the fade in again. Is there a way to only do it on the first change? So only in length goes greater than 0 or less than 1, but not if it goes from 1 to 2, for example. Oh, and if it changes to something, it'll show up really quick, fade out the new one, then fade it back in.

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7ku8jyfz/)***

I would rather restructure your elements a little, and use a cross fade with css opacity and transitioning.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').on('input',function(){
       var len = $('#search').val().length;
       var text = $(".productDisplay div:visible").text();
       if( len == 0 ){
           if( text == "All Products" ) return;
           $('.showAll').css('opacity',1);
           $('.searchProducts').css('opacity',0);
       }
       if( len > 0 ){
           if( text == "Searching Products" ) return;
           $('.searchProducts').css('opacity',1);
           $('.showAll').css('opacity',0);
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.productDisplay{
    position:relative;
}
.productDisplay div{
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.searchProducts{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text">
    <h1 id="products">
        <div class="productDisplay">
            <div class="showAll">All Products</div>
            <div class="searchProducts">Searching Products</div>
        </div>
    </h1>
```